# PHP: Getting value of a function

Tags: php, mysql

It's the first time I want to use a function in a PHP script. Somehow I cannot get the value returned from the function.

Here is the relevant part of my script:

```
// FUNCTIONS
// ---------
function getActivityName($event_types_id) {
        $query_activity_name = "SELECT * FROM event_types WHERE id=$event_types_id";
        $results_activity_name = $db->query($query_activity_name);
        while ($result_activity_name = $results_activity_name -> fetch_assoc()) {
            $activity_name = $result_activity_name['title'];
        }
        echo $activity_name;
}   

// DO SEARCH AND OUTPUT RESULTS
// ----------------------------
$results = $db -> query($query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {

    while ($result = $results -> fetch_assoc()) {

        $response = '<div class="admin_event">';
        $response .= '<a href="events-single.php?event_id='.$result['id'].'"><h3>' . $result['title'] . '</h3></a>';
        $response .= '<p>' . getActivityName($result['event_types_id']) . '</p>';
        $response .= '<p>' . $result['start'] . '</p>';
        $response .= '</div>';
        echo $response;
    }

} else {
    $response = '<p class="no_results">No results found. Please modify your selection.';
    echo $response;
```

}

My goal is to get the activity name in my $response-loop based on the event_types_id. What is wrong about my usage of the function?

**EDIT:**

The code does **not** work when I use "return" instead of "echo" at the end of the function getActivityName(). It only works when I use the function code inside my $response loop:

```
// DO SEARCH AND OUTPUT RESULTS
// ----------------------------
$results = $db -> query($query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {

    while ($result = $results -> fetch_assoc()) {

        // get name of event type
        $event_types_id = $result['event_types_id'];
        $query_activity_name = "SELECT * FROM event_types WHERE id=$event_types_id";
        $results_activity_name = $db->query($query_activity_name);
        while ($result_activity_name = $results_activity_name -> fetch_assoc()) {
            $activity_name = $result_activity_name['title'];
        }


        $response = '<div class="admin_event">';
        $response .= '<a href="events-single.php?event_id='.$result['id'].'"><h3>' . $result['title'] . '</h3></a>';
        $response .= '<p>' . $activity_name . '</p>';
        $response .= '<p>' . $result['start'] . '</p>';
        $response .= '</div>';
        echo $response;
    }

} else {
    $response = '<p class="no_results">No results found. Please modify your selection.';
    echo $response;
```

}

**Why does this version work but not my function version above?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are echoing `$activity_name`.  You want to `return` it so that the returned value can be assigned.

Instead of:

```
echo $activity_name;
```

Use:

```
return $activity_name;
```

Also, you should be developing with `error_reporting` enabled:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

This would tell you that `$db` is not an object, as well as other issues.  You need to pass in `$db` for it to be available in the function.  Also, you have an unused var and you don't need a loop for one record.  Consider using `LIMIT` as well:

```
function getActivityName($db, $event_types_id) {
        $query_activity_name = "SELECT * FROM event_types WHERE id=$event_types_id LIMIT 1";
        $results_activity_name = $db->query($query_activity_name);
        $activity_name = $results_activity_name->fetch_assoc();

        return $activity_name['title'];
}
```

Call it with:

```
getActivityName($db, $result['event_types_id'])
```

Comment: I tried it with "return", but still get no output. I only get the ouput when i use the getActivityName code inside the $response loop. See my edited answer --> do you know why it works then but not with a function?

Comment: Added a little.  However, I would assume that a JOIN would work better than querying in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [return](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) keyword to return the value.

Use `return $activity_name;` to return the value

[Echo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) is used to Output one or more strings